# How to get datatable input field checkbox checked value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I have an input field checkbox in datatable. How can I get values of the checked checkbox?

```
<form method="post"><tr>
<td ></td>
<td ><input type="checkbox" name="multicheck[]" class="multicheck" 
 value='.$value['id'].' /> </td>
</tr>
</form>
```

I have not copied the entire table above.

Thanks.

Comment: First could you post what you have tried?
second there are a few different ways... https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-check-a-checkbox-is-checked-or-not-using-jquery.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do a selector like this:

Get all checked elements:
`document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')`

Than you could transform the nodelist to an array and map to extract only the values:

```js
const checkedValues = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
].map(check => check.value);
```

#### Example:

```js
document.querySelector("#btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
  const checkedValues = [
    ...document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')
  ].map(check => check.value);
  console.log("checked values", checkedValues);
});
```

```html
<input id="xyz" type="checkbox" name="multicheck[]" class="multicheck" value="xyz" />
<label for="xyz">xyz</label>
<input id="abc" type="checkbox" name="multicheck[]" class="multicheck" value="abc" />
<label for="abc">abc</label>
<button id="btn">get checked values</button>
```

Small demo https://codesandbox.io/s/checkbox-demo-oeiu5

Comment: I have allowed myself to insert your solution as a snippet, which you can test the solution right away. I strongly encourage you to give solutions in this way, because it will remain here forever. Examples on the external server may disappear.

Comment: @ion this code only picking current page checkboxes in datatable , not the entire

Comment: Could you give me a demo sample of what you are trying to do @arvindpundir?

Comment: @Ion https://prnt.sc/qb580k I have attached a datatable screenshot , its a admin panel so I cant give you access

Comment: Now I get the problem, the datatable is paginated so you can't rely on a css selector to select all checked elements. That information must be suplied from your backed service or if all the data is present on the client, you must iterate through all the datasoure from that datatable. @arvindpundir

Answer (score 0):

Hope this works

```js
const values = [];
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input.multicheck');

for(let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++){
   if( inputs[i].checked ){
      values.push( inputs[i].value );
    }
}

console.log(values)
```

Then variable values will have the values of the checked checkboxs